# Read last byte from file and truncate to size

Tags: java, file-io

I have a huge set of files, to all of which there is (should be) a sentinel character (1 byte) appended to the end of file. How can I read the very last byte (to ensure it is the character) and truncate it to size (ie: remove the character)?

I know I could read the whole thing, and write it all back minus the last character, but there's got to be a way to get to a specific byte, isn't there?

Comment: Seems dangerous to me. What if a regular file has that special byte?

Comment: @tafa I am working on a specific set of files, I know it's safe to remove it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the RandomAccessFile class to seek to the end of the file, read it, and then truncate the file using [`setLength()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#setLength%28long%29).

**Update:** Here's some code:

```
File target = new File("/path/to/file");
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(target,"rwd");
file.seek(target.length()-1); // Set the pointer to the end of the file
char c = file.readChar();
if(c == '|') // Change the pipe character to whatever your sentinel character is
{
     file.setLength(target.length()-1); // Strip off the last _byte_, not the last character
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this code, no error handling, etc.

If the file is in any non-8-bit character set, the `target.length()-1` will need to be adjusted.

Comment: +1 + check for writing code, though I didn't need it. But RandomAccessFile is exactly what I was looking for.

And yeah, apparently every single method in RandomAccessFile throws an IOException.

Comment: `file.readChar()` makes no sense here, except if the data was written using a `DataOutput` or a compatible encoding (I think UTF-16LE). In no case it works for the specified *sentinel character (1 byte)*. Using `readByte()` would be appropriate.