# How to delete content of a file programatically without deleting file or without creating a new file with same name?

Tags: java

I need to delete content of a file. I know that I can delete file and create with same name, but I don't want to do that. I am using PrintWriter object for writing to file. Specifically I don't want to perform any action other that writing, reading and deleting content to file.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Bipin

Comment: PrintWriter can't have anything like that, as it's not specific to files. What would it even mean to "delete content" when the PrintWriter was attached to a network stream?

Comment: I think the question is probably:  If I have a pipe to a file with a PrintWriter, can I delete the contents of the file programmatically?

Comment: Yes, I mean to say can I delete the content of file without creating a new file with the same name?

Comment: I think he wants to TRUNCATE the file to reduce it to zero bytes, leaving the file existing, but empty. PrintWriter cannot help you here.

Comment: Check this posting:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301445/read-last-byte-from-file-and-truncate-to-size

Comment: I think when you open a file in printwriter it truncates it to zero. So you get an empty file each time you open it.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintWriter pw= new PrintWriter(file);
.......ur code....
pw.flush(); //Flush all contents on Stream
```

Will this help you?

Comment: flush() does not delete content of file or PrintWriter object. I want to delete content of file.

Answer (score 0):

Question is meaningless. PrintWriter doesn't have any content to delete, unless you are referring to the internal buffer, which can be flushed but not cleared.

Does maybe File.delete() answer your question?

Comment: As I mentioned I do not want to delete the file. I need to delete content of file programatically without creating a new file with same name.

Comment: @bipinbihari Why? What's the difference? to you I mean. There is a way to truncate the file, with `RandomAccessFile`, now that you have finally made your requirement clear, but why not just recreate the file?

Comment: I have an API getWriter() which returns PrintWriter Object (Singleton), basically this object is made for wrting log data. This way I need not create file and need not worry about exceptions, the API takes care of that. I tried creating new PrintWriter with new file, but does not write anything to log. The objective of writing log data is successful if I use the PrintWriter returned by the API. Currently log is getting appended on every ActionEvent. I need to clear the log on every ActionEvent and then write only latest message to the log.

Comment: @bipinbihari So you have mis-designed your system. You can't do that. You will have to change your API to return something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
printWriter.write("".toCharArray());
```