# file.setLength or rewrite contents to another file

Tags: java, file

If i'd have a problem like this:

[Read last byte from file and truncate to size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301445/read-last-byte-from-file-and-truncate-to-size)

it's faster to write the contents, except the last char, of the file to another file , or is it better to use the setLength to resize the original file?

Comment: I would expect the setLength to always be faster, especially on a large file.  I guess OS / Filesystem / Hardware / JVM differences could come into play but I think setLength is a safe choice.

Comment: Writing the whole content of the file to another file would use more resources: require more processing time, disk access, etc. If the task is simply to remove a single char from the end of the file, then the fastest way would be to use setLength.

Comment: Me too, but I asked it here because I dont know how setLenght works, and I tougth that it could even be rewriting the contents ( behind the scenes)

Comment: Well if it does it is no slower than doing that yourself, and if it doesn't it is faster, so there is no reason not to use it.